# Placing icons to action bar

Tags: android

I am placing icons to action bar. It looks like this:

[image]

Why search icon is more white? I want to do same color with setting icon. How can I do this?

My xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:title="Takip Listesi"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
      android:title="Settings"
      android:showAsAction="always" />
```

My images:

http://www.imgim.com/ic_action_search.png

http://imgim.com/image/ic_action_settings.png

**Note: Images are white, probably you can't see on browser. Please download it.**

Comment: Both links that you provided contains images with some transparency, maybe you edited the magnifier icon, or saved as an image type that doesn't support transparency?

Comment: Your settings icon probably has some transparency.

Comment: Yeah, I added some transparency to search icon then it solved. Thank you.